# Angular userForm.valid timing issue. Screen is rendered while userForm.valid is still undefiled

Tags: javascript, angular

I seem to be having a timing issue and userForm.valid is not set on initial refresh of my screen. By the time I see the page, userForm.valid is set to true. but in the mean time, errors are dumped to the chrome development console. How do I wait for this code to complete before rendering the screen? Running Angular: 11.2.12

user-add.component.ts

```
  userForm: FormGroup;
  . . .
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getUserForm();
    });
  }

  private getUserForm(): void {
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(this.user.id),
      active: new FormControl(this.user.active),
      name: new FormControl(this.user.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(50)
      ]),
      email: new FormControl(this.user.email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.pattern("(?!.*[\\+|#|$|%|^|\\*|\\?]).*")
      ]),
      homeBranches: new FormControl(this.userHomeBranches)
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p> userForm.valid </p>
    <pre>{{ userForm.valid }} </pre>
</div>
```

**Console.log:**
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valid')

**Once the screen refresh is complete:**
userForm.valid
true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
userForm.valid
```

to

```
userForm?.valid
```

The `?` operator indicates that the object might be undefined.

You can also use `*ngIf` to make sure the form is set

```
<div *ngIf="userForm">
    <p> userForm?.valid </p>
    <pre>{{ userForm?.valid }} </pre>
</div>
```